# <Mac M1> Mysql ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: apple-m1, mysql-error-1045

I've tried everything I've even uninstalled and installed versions MySQL 8.0.0 all the way up to 8.0.28.

I'm on a Mac M1
Here's what I've tried:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Applied Password from the install*

This is what I got back:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Stop Mysql Server
Quit Terminal

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

Received:

```
2022-04-06T22:28:02.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/mysql/data/cyndrias-MBP.lan.err'.
2022-04-06T22:28:02.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/data
2022-04-06T22:28:03.6NZ mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/mysql/data/cyndrias-MBP.lan.pid ended
```

Stop Mysql Server
Quit Terminal

Input:

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root
```

entered Password*

Received:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Comment: have you found out any solution?

Comment: My solution was downloading docker mysql. This worked for me. Follow this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kphq2TsVRIs

Comment: I have the same question. I try to uninstall MYSQL and reinstall it, but it dosen't work. And finally I change the `my.cnf` file in your MySQL file path(but `etc/` path) , key:'user', value change to 'root', and now I can open MySQL with sudo and using sqld just with sudo. I don't know whether who has a best idea to solve it. Maybe this can help you~

Answer (score 0):

How are you launching mysql? I found that adding the `--skip-grant-table` flag allows me to connect without a password on the first entry. So for me, this looks like:

```
mysql.server start --skip-grant-table
```

Then to connect:

```
mysql -u root -p
```